# How to decode this json in C#

Tags: json.net

I'm trying AlphaVantage API to get stock values.
With postman I get this response
`{ "Global Quote": { "01. symbol": "VK.PAR", "02. open": "10.2300", "03. high": "10.3500", "04. low": "10.1400", "05. price": "10.3200", "06. volume": "751332", "07. latest trading day": "2023-06-28", "08. previous close": "10.2150", "09. change": "0.1050", "10. change percent": "1.0279%" } }`

How can I decode this json in C# with newtonsoft.
I need your help.

Comment: The documentation in the carousel at the very top of the [home page](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) seems to cover that. Did you make an attempt that failed? A [mcve] would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can deserialize 2 ways. to class (have limited set of items or to dictionary, but you will need to unbox values to proper type or use as strings..)

```
    string jsonresult = "{\"Global Quote\": { \"01. symbol\": \"VK.PAR\", \"02. open\": \"10.2300\", \"03. high\": \"10.3500\", \"04. low\": \"10.1400\", \"05. price\": \"10.3200\", \"06. volume\": \"751332\", \"07. latest trading day\": \"2023-06-28\", \"08. previous close\": \"10.2150\", \"09. change\": \"0.1050\", \"10. change percent\": \"1.0279%\" } }";
//to class with static properties
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonresult).Dump();
//to class as dictionary
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root2>(jsonresult).Dump();
```

now in this example i bound to Root class and Root2 class

so class example would be:

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("Global Quote")]
    public GlobalQuote GlobalQuote { get; set; }
}

public class GlobalQuote
{
    [JsonProperty("01. symbol")]
    public string _01symbol { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("02. open")]
    public string _02open { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("03. high")]
    public string _03high { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("04. low")]
    public string _04low { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("05. price")]
    public string _05price { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("06. volume")]
    public string _06volume { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("07. latest trading day")]
    public string _07latesttradingday { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("08. previous close")]
    public string _08previousclose { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("09. change")]
    public string _09change { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("10. change percent")]
    public string _10changepercent { get; set; }
}
```

result:
[image]

this is for dictionary:

```
public class Root2
{
    [JsonProperty("Global Quote")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> GlobalQuote { get; set; }
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I choose the first method.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
Dictionary<string,string> globalQuote = JObject.Parse(json)["Global Quote"]
                                                .ToObject<Dictionary<string,string>>();
```